# A single column with many values separated by semicolon, R

Tags: r

I have a column with 1000 rows. Each row has 5000 values all separated with semicolon. I like to turn this column into a matrix of 1000 x 5000 dimension.
How can I do this in R?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: `read.csv2` if you want a data.frame

Comment: `library(splitstackshape);
cSplit(df, 'V1', sep=";", type.convert=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
as.numeric(strsplit(A[,1],";"))
```

if the data is in a dataframe or array

```
as.numeric(strsplit(A,";"))
```

if the data is a vector

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it.

```
my_data <- data.frame(one_column = c("5;6;5;6;7", "6;5;3;2;5"))
my_data
        one
1 5;6;5;6;7
2 6;5;3;2;5

# split each row by a semicolon
my_list <- apply(my_data, 1, strsplit, split = ";")

# unlist and turn it into a matrix
my_matrix <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(my_list)), nrow = nrow(my_data), 
                    ncol =length(my_list[[1]][[1]]), byrow = TRUE)
my_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    6    5    6    7
[2,]    6    5    3    2    5
```

You could specify the number of rows and columns if you would like.  Here I am assuming that you do indeed have 5000 values for each row.

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked beautifully :)

Comment: if it worked please up vote the solution so that it is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start creating an example of this dataframe that contains 1 column with 
semicolon separated values:

```
d <- data.frame(col1 = paste0(runif(1000), ";", runif(1000), ";", runif(1000)), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

This is how the dataframe looks like:

```
head(d)
                                                    col1
1   0.20093023753725;0.399978927802294;0.404899704502895
2 0.424904063809663;0.0908958145882934;0.340853224741295
3  0.850118306931108;0.518901573261246;0.364027933450416
4 0.0212442732881755;0.760768163017929;0.146710442844778
5 0.0331723166164011;0.153021499980241;0.449281473178416
6 0.733110485365614;0.0544649658259004;0.663546974770725
```

The following 2 lines of code produce what you want:

```
library(stringr)

t <- str_split(d$col1, ";")
d2 <- do.call(rbind, t)
```

The first line produces a list where each element contains the split values.
The second line binds them all together in a matrix.